# CvSVM.predict() gives 'NaN' output and low accuracy

Tags: opencv, svm

I am using CvSVM to classify only two types of facial expression. I used LBP(Local Binary Pattern) based histogram to extract features from the images, and trained using `cvSVM::train(data_mat,labels_mat,Mat(),Mat(),params)`, where,

data_mat is of size 200x3452, containing normalized(0-1) feature histogram of 200 samples in row major form, with 3452 features each(depends on number of neighbourhood points)

labels_mat is corresponding label matrix containing only two value 0 and 1.
The parameters are:

CvSVMParams params;

```
params.svm_type     =CvSVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type  =CvSVM::LINEAR;
params.C            =0.01;
params.term_crit=cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,(int)1e7,1e-7);
```

The problem is that:-

1. while testing I get very bad result (around 10%-30% accuracy), even after applying with different kernel and train_auto() function.
2. `CvSVM::predict(test_data_mat,true)` gives 'NaN' output

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, that your classes linearly hard/non-separable in feature space you use.
May be it will be better to apply PCA to your dataset before classifier training step
and estimate effective dimensionality of this problem.
Also I think it will be userful test your dataset with other classifiers.
You can adapt for this purpose standard opencv example points_classifier.cpp.
It includes a lot of different classifiers with similar interface you can play with.

Answer (score 1):

The SVM generalization power is low.In the first reduce your data dimension by principal component analysis then change your SVM kerenl type to RBF.